# Strategy for creating class

Tags: .net, performance

This is first way:

```
Public Class MyClass
     Private _Property As String

     Property Property () As String
         Get
             Return _Property 
         End Get
         Set(ByVal Value As String)
             _Property = Value
         End Set
     End Property

    Public Function DoSomething() As String
        Return _Property & Now()
    End Function  
End Class
```

Also I can do it in this way:

```
Public Class MyClass

    Public Property As String

    Public Function DoSomething() As String
        Return Property & Now()
    End Function  

End Class
```

Which way is preferred?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shorter way is preferred (by me) because it's easier to read and understand. You can always switch to a fully written property definition if you need to do something special.

Some remarks though.

You should always use the property getter (Property) inside your code. Never use the internal variable (_Property). This is important because this way all interaction with that internal variable goes through a single point which you can than easily modify. Perhaps you want to format the property or throw an exception when the value is incorrect, etc. So the DoSomething function should be exactly the same in both methods.

```
Public Function DoSomething() As String
  Return Me.Property & Now()
End Function
```

Finally the Property shorthand is incorrect. It should be:

```
Public Property [Property] as String
```

You didn't give it a name. I assume you want to name it 'Property'. I assume this is a reserved word and thus you probably would run into issues. By declaring it like this the compiler won't trip over it. But you'd be wise to avoid reserved words in your class & method names.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question depends, what you want to achive...

In the first way, you "hide" the information from the "user". If you are writing code for yourself and you know exactly what you do, then you can do it like the second way.

But most commonly it is bad style to use public properties. Because when you do this, you lose the control over the public property, because anyone can change it, without using the getter/setter.

So if you are writing something like an API, you should never use public properties, because you want to STRICTLY limit the access to your properties...

For instance: If you use the first way, but delete the Set method and initialize the property by yourself in a constructor. Then there is no way to change the property from outside, because it is private. But you can still "ask" your class from the outside world, Get() and you will receive exactly what you defined.

Information hiding is used, to prevent other "dumb" programmers to misuse your class and getting false results...

Comment: Wouldn't you just use 'Private Property' if you want to hide properties from outside classes? Your answer doesn't make much sense to me, sorry. Code hiding is important but not the issue here. The most important thing is to make everything go through properties and only acces the properties themselves and never the internal variables. If you want to change the internal behavior of a setter or a getter later on you can just write it out manually. But always make sure you go through setters & getters.

Comment: @SpoBo The question is more complex... Of course you are also right. You can use the second way and save LOC with it. But when you work at a larger company and someone else is using/maintaining/improving your code later, then they ALWAYS make mistakes with it. And your very first sentence: I disaggree strongly! You should see it the other way round: You SOLELY should make a property public, if you have strong reasons for that (and there are only very few reasons to me). Default should be private!

Comment: I agree that a property should only be public if you think it'll be needed outside of the class. Stuff that is only important to the internal code of the class should be private. But then just write 'Private Property [PropertyName] as String'. If you need to make a private property publicly available readonly, create a new ReadOnly property with a different name that just returns the private property in the getter. Anyway, this discussion is completely off track :p The question is much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would spell `MyClass` correctly ;)

If your way accomplishes what Microsoft suggests, then your way is preferred. Your code is short and sweet. However, I would recommend to do it your way only if you have a strong understanding of what is going on. I've run down the road way too many times of reinventing the wheel when I didn't have to.

Comment: No worries. Answering your question is what matters.